# TypeError: unbound method lookAtFixationPointSync() must be called with IGazeControl instance as first argument (got list instance instead)

Tags: python, yarp

Hello everyone, 
              Given below is my piece of code and i am having the above error mentioned in title. can anyone please help me in this case, where i am having error. All helps are appreciated. Thanks

```
import yarp;
import numpy;
import math;
import time;
from yarp import IGazeControl

props = yarp.Property()
props.put("device","remote_controlboard")
props.put("local","/client/head")
props.put("remote","/icubSim/head")

print("Server Running")

yarp.Network.init()
if yarp.Network.checkNetwork() != True:
    print ("[error] Please try running yarp server")
    quit()

igaze2=yarp.IGazeControl


fp = [None]*3
fp[0] = -0.50
fp[1]=+0.0+0.1*math.cos(2.0*math.pi*0.1*1)
fp[2]=+0.3+0.1*math.sin(2.0*math.pi*0.1*2)

print("value of fp is",fp)


igaze2.lookAtFixationPointSync(fp)
igaze2.waitMotionDone()
```

Comment: `igaze2 = yarp.IGazeControl()` - maybe you'll have to provide some args as well.

Comment: it says that IGazeControl() is an abstract class with no constructor. i created a separate class and inherited IGazecontrol class into it and then created object of that class but problem remains the same.